# Racket function for finding minimum element of list given a function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

Is there some function in Racket(Scheme) that can give me the element, which produces the minimum value after applying a given function in a list.
Something like `(apply min (map f list))` but returning the element before applying f.
For example:

```
(define lst '((1 . 3) (3 . 8) (5 . 6))
(define (f pair)
  (- (cdr pair) (car pair)))
(minimum f lst)
```

This should give `'(5 . 6)`.

There should be a one liner for this with higher order functions at least if there is no direct function(as I had to fill in one line to get this behaviour).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`argmin`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=min#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._argmin%29%29):

```
#lang racket

(define lst '((1 . 3) (3 . 8) (5 . 6)))
(define (f pair)
  (- (cdr pair) (car pair)))
(argmin f lst)
```

produces `'(5 . 6)` as you desired.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this generic version](https://docs.racket-lang.org/relation/Order_Relations.html#%28def._%28%28lib._relation%2Forder..rkt%29._min%29%29) of `min`, which accepts a `key` argument:

```
(require relation)
(apply min #:key f lst)
```

`=> '(5 . 6)`

This version of `min` also works on strings or any other orderable type (i.e. not just numbers).

*[disclosure: I'm the author of this library]*